# Align elements on page

Tags: html, css

Need to allign text ant input text boxes in HTML page. I don't wont to count spaces after `Name` to make it the same size like `Surname`. What is the right way to do this?

I have :

```
Name INPUT_BOX
Surname INPUT_BOX
```

I need to have:

```
Name    INPUT_BOX
Surname INPUT_BOX
```

HTML code:

```
Name <input value ="aaa" >
<br>
Surname <input value = "bbb" >
```

Should I use CSS or HTML is enough?

Comment: You'll need to us css and html - there's a billion form examples out there, just google e.g. "html css form example"

Comment: set a width that suit for both `name` and `surname`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/gaka0yt0/

The simplest variant is

```
<div>
    <label> Name </label> <input value ="aaa" >
</div>

label 
{
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you requested, check this sample form

```css
body{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
}
.content{
padding:10px;
width:370px
}
.left{
width:150px;
float:left;
padding:7px 0px 0px 7px;
min-height:24px;
}
.right{
width:200px;
float:left;
padding:5px;
min-height:24px;
}
.clear{
float:none;
clear:both;
height:0px;
}
.row{
background-color:none;
display:block;
min-height:32px;
}
.text{
width:190px;
}
.ruler{
width:400px; border-bottom:dashed 1px #dcdcdc;
}
tr:focus{
background-color:#fcfcf0;
}
td{
vertical-align:top;
}
.over{
background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
.out{
background-color:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
   <h3>Sample web form</h3>
<div class="content">
<div class="row">
<div class="left">Name</div>
<div class="right"><input name="Text1" type="text" class="text" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="left">Surname</div>
<div class="right"><input name="Text1" type="text" class="text" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="left">Email</div>
<div class="right"><input name="Text1" type="text" class="text" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="left">Password</div>
<div class="right"><input name="Text1" type="text" class="text" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<hr />


</form>
</body>
</html>
```